# Changing variables after release

Tags: ios, security, rest, in-app-purchase

I am working on an iOS game in which the user can buy some improvements. Basically, this improvement just change some game variables (i.e. `speedOfHero=4.5`). To stay flexible (and allow late game balancing), I was thinking about this architecture:

- Having a class who provides those dynamic constant, let's name it `ConstantProvider`, which has a method who returns a constant given a key (here a string).
- Fetching key-value records from an HTTP REST server.
- Let the user buy those records and implement `ConstantProvider` in function of the records the user had bought.

However, I was wondering if this approach is secure. Indeed, since the constant value are not hard-coded in the app, but fetched from a remote server, I can imagine someone impersonating the server and changing the value for a key (i.e. `punchStrength=INT_MAX`). However, even if it can be harder, hard-coded values can be changed too. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to the server could be only to determine if the upgrade has been purchased. You should be able to obscure that request so that it is not easily duped. Then, your code can just verify whether the upgrade was purchased, and if so, increase the constants.

Comment: What do you mean by `obscure that request` here?

Comment: If I understood well, the constants here are hard-coded in the app and I cannot change them after release.

Comment: "Obscure that request" could be simply generate a token via a hash known both by the client and server, and including the current date time. That way, when the client decrypts the token, it can verify that it was generated "recently" and therefore came from the server.  Then in your client code you have "if UPGRADE WAS PURCHASED then HitStrenght = Max else HitStrength = Normal"